# Force loading assemblies in webassembly project - MEF - AvaloniaUI

Tags: c#, webassembly, mef, reactiveui, avaloniaui

**Problem:**
When using MEF with webassembly the composition is not working.

**My setup:**
I have a AvaloniaUI project with ReactiveUI as MVVM Framework. To load modules I have added MEF.
I have multiple projects.

- Module A
- Module B
- Shell
- Startup.Desktop
- Startup.Browser

The startup projects have a reference to the shell project.
In the Shell project the bootstrapping is in the App.xaml.cs, here I initialize my Logger, IoC and the modules.

At the beginning I was using a `DirectoryCatalog` but there were no modules found when using the browser startup.
I switched to `ApplicationCatalog` and added all modules as reference to the startup projects.
With the desktop startup everything works, with the browser it still does not work.
I even added stuff like

```
IModule _ = new ModuleA();
_ = new ModuleB();
```

to my browser Program at the very beginning to make sure the module assemblies are downloaded.

**Browser Program**

```
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    TestLoad();
    var appBuilder = BuildAvaloniaApp();
    var app = appBuilder.Instance as App;
    await appBuilder.WithInterFont()
        .UseReactiveUI()
        .StartBrowserAppAsync("out");
    app?.Dispose();
}

public static AppBuilder BuildAvaloniaApp()
{
    return AppBuilder.Configure<App>();
}

private static void TestLoad()
{
    IModule _ = new ModuleA();
    _ = new ModuleB();
}
```

**Desktop Program**

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var appBuilder = BuildAvaloniaApp();
    var app = appBuilder.Instance as App;
    appBuilder.StartWithClassicDesktopLifetime(args);
    app?.Dispose();
}

public static AppBuilder BuildAvaloniaApp()
    => AppBuilder.Configure<App>()
        .UsePlatformDetect()
        .WithInterFont()
        .LogToTrace()
        .UseReactiveUI();
```

**Bootstrapping**

```
public override void OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()
{
    var programVersion = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
    _logger = LoggerConfigurationHelper.ConfigureLogger();
    _logger.Info("  ====================  Application Startup  ====================  ");
    _logger.Info($"Current {StringConstants.ProductName} version: {programVersion}");
    _logger.Debug("Registering services");

    var moduleLoader = new ModuleLoader(_logger);

    _host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
        {
            services.UseMicrosoftDependencyResolver();
            var resolver = Locator.CurrentMutable;
            resolver.InitializeSplat();
            resolver.InitializeReactiveUI();
            resolver.UseNLogWithWrappingFullLogger();

            services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger), _logger);
            services.AddSingleton(typeof(IModuleLoader), moduleLoader);

            services.AddTransient<MainWindowViewModel>();
            services.AddTransient<MainViewModel>();
            Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => new MainView(), typeof(IViewFor<MainViewModel>));

            foreach (var module in moduleLoader.Modules)
                module.Value.Register(services);
        })
        .Build();
    _container = _host.Services;

    _logger.Debug("Registering services finished");
    if (ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime desktop)
        desktop.MainWindow = new MainWindow { DataContext = _container.GetService<MainWindowViewModel>() };
    else if (ApplicationLifetime is ISingleViewApplicationLifetime singleViewPlatform)
        singleViewPlatform.MainView = new MainView { DataContext = _container.GetService<MainViewModel>() };
    else
    {
        const string error = "Can not build up shell: unknown application lifetime type";
        _logger.Fatal(error);
        throw new Exception(error);
    }
```

**Module loading**

```
[ImportMany(typeof(IModule), AllowRecomposition = false)]
private IEnumerable<Lazy<IModule>>? _modules;

public Dictionary<string, IModule> Modules { get; } = new();

public ModuleLoader(ILogger logger)
{
    _logger = logger;

    var catalog = new ApplicationCatalog();
    var compositionContainer = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
    compositionContainer.ComposeParts(this);
    
    DiscoverModules();
}

private void DiscoverModules()
{
    _logger.Debug("Searching modules");

    if (_modules == null)
    {
        _logger.Error("Modules could not be loaded");
        return;
    }

    _logger.Debug($"{_modules.Count()} modules found");
    foreach (var module in _modules)
    {
        _logger.Debug($"Module found: {module.Value.Name}");
        Modules[module.Value.Name] = module.Value;
    }
    _logger.Debug("Finished discovering modules");
}
```

If I have a breakpoint in the ModuleLoader constructor I can see that with browser startup the `_modules` are empty after they should have been injected.

The exception says `Unable to resolve service for type ISomeService`.
This should be injected into the MainViewModel, but does not work because the module could not register it.

**Why does MEF fail loading the modules for the webassembly variant?**